# Quickbook PHP framework - imports an Invoice twice periodically

Tags: php, mysql, quickbooks

Very rarely, we are finding that an invoice is imported into quickbooks twice. Looking into the quickbooks_queue table we see that the transaction is in there with a 'S' status, and immediatly after ( 1 minute to be exact ) the same transactions ident with an 'S'.

As we have never had this problem before I have no idea where to start! there does not seem to be pattern - the only thing that I can think of is that table rows (MyIsam) are being locked by other users so the QB Web Connector cannot access the row to set it as already imported, which then gets picked up and re-queued because of the lack of 'qb_imported' value on the invoice?

I haven't posted code as its pretty extensive - and Im not sure that the problem is truly in the code ...

Comment: I should add that the system only queues an invoice if it doesn't find its IDENT in the queue AND its qb_imported/qb_id columns are blank. If the ID is fond in the queue then it assumes it is about to be imported and ignores it ( ignoring error codes too ) and if the invoice already has QB ID attached to it then it must have been imported.

Examining the raw QB database table showed the duplicated invoice but with a different txn_id and invoice_no - surely this shouldn't have been able to happen?

Answer (score 0):

> Looking into the quickbooks_queue table we see that the transaction is in there with a 'S' status, and immediatly after ( 1 minute to be exact ) the same transactions ident with an 'S'.

The only way that can happen (two records in the table) is if you inserted (queued up) two records.

What are you doing that's allowing two records to be queued up?

Without seeing your code (or at least a description of how you're queuing things up) I don't know that anyone will be able to help you any further.

Comment: The Queue Up function is supposed to check the existing queue table for the given ident - if it finds a success (s) marker then it should not add that invoice to the queue again. I think I may have a race condition - I will post the offending code on Monday if I havent found the issue by then. 

Our queue is set manually - once the accounts team are happy for the transaction to go to QB they simply hit Queue, which checks that the invoice can be queued first - I think there may be a problem in the code that checks if its already been queued - I dont have a check inplace for 'in-progress' ...